# automatically select a value in a combobox in Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, listbox

I have an access program to handle inventory.

there is a listbox with values in it, I am trying to have the combobox updated with a value from the list box when clicked. The combobox has specific values in it, and there will only ever be thos values in the list box.

so far I have this:

```
Me.cboLocation.TabIndex = index
```

But it is not working. I have the index value set in an ifelse statement depending on the text that comes from the list box.

```
if Me.lstItems.Column(5) = "Cage" then
    index = 0
elseif Me.lstItems.Column(5) = "Cabnet" then
    index = 1
...
```

Any idea on how I might achieve this? thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to set the value of a combobox is to assign the bound column, let us say the bound column is an ID, you would say `Me.cboLocation=124`. What is your set up?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I changed the code to:

```
Me.cboLocation = Me.lstItems.Column(5)
```

Took out the if bock. I noticed I had the Column Count set to 4, so it wasn't picking up the 5th value.